# Do Lenovo ideapad 100S and Realtek RTL8723BS support Microsoft hosted network virtual driver? In Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, lenovo-laptop, connection-sharing

I have a cheap Lenovo netbook and just learned of hosted virtual networks and hoped to set one up on the netbook which is running Windows 10 so my MacBook Air and other devices can access the Internet through it.

I followed various instructions which did not work for me and found that in my Device Manager / Network adapters I lacked the required "Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter".

Searching further I have not been able to determine for certain why this is missing.

The netbook is an ideapad 100S-11IBY. Its Wi-Fi adapter is a Realtek RTL8723BS. Could either of these simply not support this feature.

Or is it that the Windows 10 driver for the adapter doesn't support it? I've installed the latest driver and hunted for a driver for a previous Windows version to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

checkout http://www.windowscentral.com/how-turn-your-windows-10-pc-wireless-hotspot

basically.. . .

"you will first need to verify your computer's physical wireless adapter supports this feature using the following command:

NETSH WLAN show drivers

If the generated output shows Hosted network supported: Yes, then you can continue with the guide. If your wireless adapter isn't supported, you could try using a USB wireless adapter that supports the feature"